# HTML5 Clipboard API and Photoshop Transparent Pixels (PNG)

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, png, photoshop

I'm trying to select a semi-transparent texture in Photoshop and paste it into the HTML5 Clipboard API and retain its transparency.

I just spent a lot of time looking into this. I've used Photoshop to copy semi-transparent textures for some time while prototyping (with the destination of Axure RP).

Now, I've tried using the new clipboard API in html 5. I dissected the PNG files that are generated by this process.

If I use the a rectangular marquee to copy a semi-transparent texture to the browser with the clipboard API, it sets the alpha byte to FF (completely opaque).

If I use the drag and drop API to copy a "Save as Web" PNG 24 file to the browser, it works as expected and transparent pixels work (and the alpha byte is not forced to FF).

I've tried many different file formats, like 24 bit depth, altering the transparency on the layer, fill, etc.

Note: Even though Photoshop says it's 24 bit, it actually exports it as 8 bit still (along with a truck load of useless text data).

**Does anyone know if there's a workaround for getting Photoshop clipboard selections into the browser with the clipboard API so that it preserves the alpha values?**

Thanks in advance...

Update:
- I'm using Chrome Version 24.0.1312.56 m

Answer (score 0):

According to my Understanding, you need to paste Photoshop specification that currently being saved in the clipboard? 
Currently, the Clipboard API specification is not complete, its working draft with latest update on (23 Feb 2012).
If we look at section 10 of the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/):
These are mandatory mime types:

```
text/plain
text/uri-list
text/csv
text/css
text/html
application/xhtml+xml
image/png
image/jpg
image/gif
image/svg+xml
application/xml, text/xml
application/javascript
application/json
```

Your issue is depends on the browser that you using, if its implemented that feature, and supports Photoshop, then, you might be able to do so.

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#introduction

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can file a bug report with Chrome.